# htaccess rewrite rule showing error

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Please I need your help with this. I have been struggling with htaccess for a while now. 
I have an index page with links to beedy.php which must pass some parameters like

```
<a href=”beedy.php?user=1”>Link 1</a>
```

but I don’t want it to show to the users so I wrote it like this 
    Link 1 
the user value is 1 here
Which worked fine. But on beedy.php page I have another link that should take me to about us page. However,   when I click the link its showing page not found (The requested URL /mvc/bd/bolade/1/seeOtherLink /About/ was not found on this server.)
I have searched google but none was explanatory enough.

My project is structured this way.
Mvc ->bd->
The mvc is the project parent folder while bd is where I have other files that I’m working on

The index.php page is as follows

```
<html>
<head> <title>Hey</title></head>
<body>
<h1 > THIS IS HOME PAGE </h1>
<a href="bolade/1/"> Link 1 </a>
<br />
<a href="bolade/2/">Link 2</a>  

</body>
</html>
```

I have my .htaccess file structured like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On    
#RewriteBase / 

#Rewrite beedy URLs
#   Input:  user/NAME/
#   Output: beedy.php?id=userId
RewriteRule ^bolade/(\w+)/?$ beedy.php?user=$1 [L]

#this should take me to about page, or any page that starts with seeOtherLink/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ seeOtherLink /(\w+)$  $1.php     

</IfModule>
```

Beedy.php page is as follows

```
<html>
<head><title>Hey Beedy</title></head>
<body>
<a href="seeOtherLink/About/"> Go to About Us</a>
<br />
<a href="seeOtherLink/Contact/"> Go to Contact Us</a>
<br />

<?php
$id = $_GET['user'];
switch($id){ 
case 1:
echo "This is the First value";
break; 
case 2:
echo "This is the Second value";
break;  
} 
?>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try removing the spaces in your urls

Comment: I did but still same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Beedy.php** page, the url you entered in the button is: **seeOtherLink/About/** and you are using **.htaccass** to make the url user friendly. So the page you are on have the following link: **bolade/1/**. So when you click on a link on this page it will simply add it to the current url, so the new url will be: **bolade/1/** + **seeOtherLink/About/** = **bolade/1/seeOtherLink/About/** which is not a page, nor a path. So the server will give you an error.

You must change the url: **seeOtherLink/About/** to: **http://website/seeOtherLink/About/** and ofcourse, you must also add it to your **.htaccess** file.

Hope this will help you

---

> **Updated**

So as I understand is that all your files lies under **bd folder**.
**index.php** have 2 links that both points to **beedy.php**, and then **beedy.php** have 2 links that points to **about.php** and **contact.php**

So your .htaccess file should be similar to the below:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
# -------------------------------------------

RewriteRule ^home                        index.php        [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^About                       about.php        [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^Contact                     contact.php      [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^bolade/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$     beedy.php?user=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^bolade                      beedy.php        [L,NC]

# -------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

> **Final**

I have created a project and tried your example, and it worked perfectly on my machine. Please follow the below steps carefully:

**Step 1:**
Create a new project called: **stackoverflow** on the root folder.

**Step 2:**
Create **index.php** file with the below code:

```
<html>
<head> <title>Hey</title></head>
<body>
<h1 > THIS IS HOME PAGE </h1>
<a href="bolade/1"> Link 1 </a>
<br />
<a href="bolade/2">Link 2</a>

</body>
</html>
```

**Step 3:**
Create **beedy.php** file with the below code:

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET["user"] ;

    switch ($id) {
        case 1:
            echo "This is the First value<br />" ;
            break ;

        case 2:
            echo "This is the Second value<br />" ;
            break ;
    }
?>

<html>
    <head><title>Hey Beedy</title></head>
    <body>
        <a href="/stackoverflow/about"> Go to About Us</a>
        <br />
        <a href="/stackoverflow/contact"> Go to Contact Us</a>
        <br />
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that the links point to the full url starting from the root file

**Step 4:**
Create **about.php** & **contact.php** files.

**Step 5:**
Create .htaccess file with the below code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
# -------------------------------------------

RewriteRule ^home                        index.php        [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^about                       about.php        [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^contact                     contact.php      [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^bolade/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$     beedy.php?user=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^bolade                      beedy.php        [L,NC]

# -------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

If you are still having problems, I can send you the test project I created.

Comment: Thanks. Please can u give me an example of how I can adjust that in my .htaccess file

Comment: Yes of course, but first can you please send me the structure of your project, and where are the files located ? Are they on the same directory ?

Comment: Okay thanks...  The parent folder name is 'mvc'  which has a child folder called 'bd'  inside be is where I hve htaccess file and index and about us. But I have some files inside the mvc too which . So it goes like this Mvc->bd-> htaccess, beedy.php, index.PHP and about.php

Comment: Thanks.. I have a problem with getting the user parameter in beedy.php.. Its not getting the value. And the about is not working. It just keeps adding About/ to the url each time I click the link.

Comment: @AkinniyiBodeBolade Kindly, check my final answer

Comment: Working perfectly now.. Thanks boss.